# file upload in javascript and send file through api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I'm trying to upload a file and send that via api as a file.But not getting working. Here is my used for upload and send my file to api.
But it most probably terns to the error message.

```
$(document).on('change', '#txtUploadFile', function(e){

    var files = e.target.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
       if (this.value.lastIndexOf('.xlsx') === -1){
          alert('Only ods files are allowed!');
          this.value = '';
          return;
       }
       if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
           var data = new FormData();
           for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++){
               data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
           }

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               contentType: "multipart/form-data",
               url: 'http://localhost/clicportaltest/rest/clicadmin/uploadExcel',

               data:{file:file},
               success: function(result) {
                   console.log(result);
               },
               error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4){
                   var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                   if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                       err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                       console.log(err);
                    }
                });
        } else {
            alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads!");
          }
     }
});
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Comment: How do you expect to encode your files as JSON? Or rather, what format is the server expecting the files to be in?

Comment: You used to say you were sending JSON, not you say you are sending multipart form data (which the rest of your code isn't doing). The code won't compile (it looks like you changed your mind about making a variable name plural half way through). You keep editing the code, but you still haven't told us what format the HTTP endpoint you are posting the data to is expecting the data in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
$('#submitUpload').on('click', function(){
    var file = document.getElementById("upload").files[0];
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", file);

    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://localhost/clicportaltest/rest/clicadmin/uploadExcel",
      "method": "POST",
      "processData": false,
      "contentType": false,
      "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
      "data": form
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `JSON.stringify` `data` because `FormData` doesn't have a `toJSON()` method, so it is treated as a plain object which results in `"{}"`.

You can either implement your own `FormData.prototype.toJSON` method or just convert `data` to a string or a plain object in your handler. How the stringified representation of `data` should be formatted depends entirely on how your API expects it to be.

Comment: i have changed code now,  but not responding to ajax now

Comment: @Midhun — Well, you've not changed the code in a way that makes sense or in a way that Mikael suggested.

Comment: @Midhun Your change was `data:{file:file}`, right? You don't declare a variable called `file` anywhere so your script crashes with a ReferenceError and the AJAX request is never performed. And as Quentin pointed out, your change does nothing to address the issue with your script.

Comment: also a variable file is there with file data

Comment: @Midhun — That suggests you've made an error when transcribing your code for the question.

Comment: @Midhun Start by changing `data:{file:file}` into `data: data` and add the property `processData: false` to send the data properly

Comment: but file is my method used to send data in api

Comment: No, it isn't. `data: { file: AFormDataObject }` is something handled by jQuery, not by your API. jQuery will handle it … poorly because it doesn't expect to see FormData objects there. There is probably a way to get jQuery to send the data you want, but you need to find out what format the API actually expects it to be in.